# How can I detect if a word is present on a Chrome page using selenium (Python)?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, try-except

This is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
import random
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=CD4040BE&keyMatch=CD4040BE")
time.sleep(1)
accept_and_proceed = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="consent_prompt_submit"]')
accept_and_proceed.click()

region = Select(driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="llc-cartpage-ship-to-country"]'))
region.select_by_visible_text('Italy')

continue1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="llc-cartpage-ship-to-continue"]')
continue1.click()
```

On the website there is the word ***Inventory***.
How can I detect if the word ***Inventory*** is present on the page? If it is present then print x and if it is not refresh the page until it will be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To validate if the word ***Inventory*** is present on the page you can use a `try-except{}` block inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

Code Block:

```
driver.get("https://www.ti.com/store/ti/en/p/product/?p=CD4040BE&keyMatch=CD4040BE")
Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//select[@id='llc-cartpage-ship-to-country']")))).select_by_visible_text('Italy')
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='llc-cartpage-ship-to-continue']"))).click()
while True:
    try:
        WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[contains(@class, 'u-tablet-up-only')]//span[@class='product-note product-availability' and contains(., 'Inventory')]")))
        print("x")
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        driver.refresh()
        continue
driver.quit()
```

Console Output:

```
x
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
```

Comment: Sad to tell you this but it doesn't work                                                                                              selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:

Comment: @FedericoBolo At which line?

Comment: @FedericoBolo Still not sure what didn't work for you. Code for _`refresh the page`_ and `TimeoutException` is already handled within the updated code.

Comment: @FedericoBolo You should have mentioned that at the first go almost an hour ago. Checkout the imports I have added to the answer.

Comment: Well, i would say that I am stupid.. I copied your code but I forgot to import timeoutexception. Thank you, I am really grateful. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
if(driver.getPageSource().contains("Inventory"))
{
   
}

else
{
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(response.url)   
    time.sleep(3)   
    driver.refresh()
}
```

Comment: This didn't worked too                                                                                                                            AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'getPageSource'                                              Thank you anyway for your answer, if you know how to solve the problem don't hesitate to tell me how, I would really appreciate it. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

With [SeleniumBase](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase), you can use the `self.assert_text(test)` or `self.assert_text(text, selector)` methods to assert text on a page (or in an element if the second optional selector argument is provided). You can also use the methods: `self.is_text_visible(text)` and `self.is_text_visible(text, selector)`, which return True or False.

```py
from seleniumbase import BaseCase

class DemoSiteTests(BaseCase):
    def test_demo_site(self):
        self.open("https://seleniumbase.io/demo_page")
        self.assert_text("Demo Page")
        self.assert_text("Demo Page", "h1")
```

Here's a longer example that uses those: https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_demo_site.py